# no such column: ٤۹۸ (code 1):

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, arabic

I translated my app using android studio translation editor, i get this error when running my application on android phone using Arabic as its language:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ٤۹۸ (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM photos WHERE store_id = ٤۹۸ ORDER BY photo_id ASC

The method in app_id > java > com > db > Queries  is:

```
public ArrayList<Photo> getPhotosByStoreId(int storeId) {

    ArrayList<Photo> list = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE store_id = %d", storeId);
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);  
    mCursor.moveToFirst();

    if (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {

            Photo entry = formatPhoto(mCursor);

            list.add(entry);
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: That's what you get for using `String.format()`.

Comment: this mean you looking for unreachable or unknown id contact me Mario if you still cant fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

use the full set of method arguments for [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) to properly escape your values for use in a sql statement.

```
...
ArrayList<Photo> list = new ArrayList<Photo>();
db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE store_id = ?", 
                             new String[] { storeId }); 
mCursor.moveToFirst();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `String.format(String, Object ...)`, which uses the default locale for formatting. Arabic uses different digits, causing your query to include characters that does not match what is found in your SQLite database.

To solve this, you could either avoid using `String.format()` and just do:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE store_id = " + storeId;
```

Or, if you for some reason still want string.format(), you could do:

```
Locale locale = Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();
String sql = String.format(locale, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE store_id = %d", storeId);
```